# Должна ли функция быть реализована в файле с таким же именем, как и заголовочный файл?

Tags: c, gcc, include, компиляция

Возникла проблема при использовании функции в *.c файле.

Должен ли я подключать к нему заголовочный файл с прототипом функции вида name.h (тело функции в name.c), или же можно подключить файл с прототипом и именем name2.h?

По умолчанию прототипы имеют спецификатор памяти extern. Считаю, что он не поможет.

Как действует компилятор в таких случаях?

Comment: Ответ: нет, не должна. Уточните как собираете и в чем проблема.

Comment: Подключить какой-то .h в любом случае надо, если вам надо дергать оттуда функцию, нет он не должен иметь такое же имя, как и .с-файл.  А вот в чем разница между вашими name.h и name2.h если честно я не понял

Comment: @dzhioev, Я объявил прототип функции в файле с именем, отличным от файла, где реализовано тело функции и подключил этот заголовочный файл к файлу, где используется эта функция. Компилятор выдает ошибку: "function treated as extern because it was referenced but not defined"

Comment: А каким образом вы компилируете файл/проект? Возможно файл с реализацией вы просто не включили в проект.

Comment: @YuriyOrlov с помощью make-файла. В нем посредством wildcard развернуты все *.c файлы. Заголовочные файлы указаны только некоторые, т.к. другие будут последовательно подключаться при компиляции соответствующих файлов

Comment: @Maxim Gusev, вы случайно не как static функцию объявляете?

Comment: @dzhioev да... проглядел как раз. Извините за глупый вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет не должна. Компилятор имена файлов никак не учитывает. Деректива `#include` относится к препроцессору, который отрабатывает до компилятора.